# Is it possible to set microk8s to use docker engine instead of containerd?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microk8s, containerd

First of all, I am not an expert in container orchestration tools.

I've just installed [microk8s](https://microk8s.io/) according to the guide:
https://microk8s.io/docs/

And if I run `microk8s kubectl get nodes`, I see, that my node is actually running `containerd` engine.

My application build process is set up to generate docker file and automatically create docker images, so I would like microk8s also use docker.

I used [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/) before, and now I decided to try microk8s. Now I am a bit confused, maybe it was a bad idea to stick with docker from the beginning?

Is it possible to set a docker engine for microk8s?

---

I've never used contained before, and I don't know how to prepare contained images for my app. That's why I am asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run Nvidia GPU enabled containers, I had to switch from containerd to docker in microk8s. Here's how I did that:

1. Edit `/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/kubelet`
2. Change `--container-runtime=docker` from  `remote`. Then, execute the following commands.
3. `microk8s stop`
4. `microk8s start`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need specifically docker to run pods using docker images on kubernetes.Any OCI standard runtime such as containerd, docker, CRI-O etc as OCI runtime can run docker images because they all follow same OCI standard.

microk8s does not offer the ability to choose from different OCI runtimes

Comment: So I think it's means I can easily use docker images using containerd engine. And my question doesn't make sense?

Comment: yes you can absolutely do that...kubernetes abstracts the container runtime from you so that you don't need to worry...now microk8s does not offer the ability to choose different OCI runtimes...you can use kubeadm if you want to have a choice around OCI runtimes

Comment: There are no "docker images". Please stop using this terminology, which is misleading. Images follow the open container initiative standards. So the images are called OCI images, not docker images.

Answer (score -2):

> First of all, I am not an expert in container orchestration tools.

MicroK8s is just a single snap package that can be installed on Ubuntu, as well as other Linux distributions. MicroK8s is easy to install and has a small disk and memory footprint, making it a good entry point for those interested in exploring K8s.

As you know, the container needs a runtime engine; **while the Docker is the most common container runtime used in a Pod**,  Pods can use other container runtime engines, such as CoreOS rkt, etc, etc if desired. For a container itself it makes no difference. That's the whole idea of that approach.

You can easily run your containers on microk8s.

Hope that helps.